# Necesito saber el último registro de una tabla Oracle

Tags: oracle

Por favor su apoyo necesito saber el último registro en la tabla `carga_diaria_sp` tomando como input fecha_ejecución?

```
select 

        a.telefono,
        b.origen as "LEGADO",
         (Select  CASE WHEN CNOMBRE_ARCH = 'NULL' THEN CDESCRIPCION ELSE CNOMBRE_ARCH END || ' (' || b.ope_donante  ||')'  From PT_MATRIZ_OPERADOR Where  NID_OPERADOR= b.ope_donante) OPE_DONANTE,
         (Select  CASE WHEN CNOMBRE_ARCH = 'NULL' THEN CDESCRIPCION ELSE CNOMBRE_ARCH END || ' (' || b.ope_receptor ||')'  From PT_MATRIZ_OPERADOR Where  NID_OPERADOR= b.ope_receptor) OPE_RECEPTOR,
        b.fecha_ejecucion PROGRAMACION,
        b.motivo_rechazo as "CODIGO RECHAZO",
        a.telefono as "TELEFONO"  

from 
        p_portabilidad a
        left join carga_diaria_sp b
        on a.telefono=b.telefono
where  b.ope_donante IN ('22','32')
and     b.FECHA_CREACION>=TO_DATE('20170101','yyyymmdd')
and     b.FECHA_CREACION<=TO_DATE('20180916','yyyymmdd')
        order by a.telefono
```

Answer (score 1):

El order by debe incluir:

`b.fecha_ejecucion desc`

Y si al final sólo quieres un registro como resultado, debes envolver tu consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
select * from 
  (tu consulta) 
where rownum=1;
```